# What would you call this spatula?

Tags: utensils

It's my favorite but its getting a bit worn and I've been trying to order a replacement online. I've tried "spatula with scooped sides" and "spatula with angled sides" but nothing leads to what I want. Everything I look for just leads to a regular flat spatula, or sometimes a rubber spatula, an angled spatula or even a fish spatula.

It's a slotted spatula with slightly angled sides to help scoop up food. [image]

Comment: I got some similar devices searching for “curved slotted spatula.”

Comment: It reminds me of a wok chuan, though a chuan wouldn't usually have slots in it. I don't think your spatula has a specific name--it feels like it is just a slotted spatula that is inspired by a chuan to be well suited for stir fry

Comment: I guess just search for spatula, get some coffee and sit down for an hour scrolling through amaz0n till you find something similar.

Comment: @AMtwo : that was my thought too (although, I'm used to calling them a 'wok shovel', but like you've said, I've never seen one that was slotted.

Comment: "Nylon Slotted Scoop Turner" ? [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Crestware-NY1-Slotted-Turner-Silver/dp/B0122LSIMG)

Comment: @zanlok That's exactly the same as mine! It even has that weird 9 bump grip on the handle and the hole at the end for hanging. I think an answer would also add the general description of a wok chuan/spatula though, as I was looking for something with raised sides and didn't realize this is what it was called. If you had an answer that incorporated that and the specific case with my spatula I would accept that. I guess this one just happens to be slotted.

Comment: See?! No-one knows what to actually call them ;-)

Comment: @Wolfgang Cool beans. Whatever the right answer is, at least now you have a way to get the desired replacement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't really like answering my own question, but I think there has been enough information to provide one.

The shape of the spatula appears to be based on a wok chuan or wok spatula, which have a shovel like design which helps when stir-frying dishes in a wok. However, these don't generally have a slotted design.

Credit to @AMtwo and @Joe for pointing this out.

@zanlok provided a [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0122LSIMG) on amazon that exactly matches my spatula. Apparently it is a product created by Crestware. The description, "Nylon Slotted Scoop Turner" only returns results for the same product from Crestware, so I'm not sure it's a good general description.

@Tetsujin provided **egg slice**, and while I appreciate and have upvoted the answer, I think it more describes a wider spatula but doesn't include the raised sides that the wok spatula has.

I would guess that the best description would be "slotted wok spatula". However, I suspect that my actual spatula was only created out of an effort by a company to produce as many varying types of kitchen utensils so as to increase sales of said utensils. While I still like it, the functions I use it for may be better filled by either a slotted spatula or a wok chuan/spatula.

Answer (score 7):

It's an **egg slice** - like a fish slice but more curved & wider.
It's for flipping/serving fried eggs… though tbh I just use a fish slice for anything like that.

Your only problem with searching it is 'egg slice' brings up a million hits for slicing eggs, so 'egg slice spatula' or 'egg fish slice spatula' might hone it down a bit. Lots of manufacturers have many things that vary in shape between the two profiles, egg or fish.

I always think half the issue with this is that no-one else knows it's properly called an egg slice either - so searching gets pretty tough.
You might get a better set of hits with 'egg turner spatula' as it seems many people call them an egg turner.
It does also look a bit like a slotted chuan, but if you search chuan, you don't get holes.

Comment: A fish slice seems to be a UK term for spatula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_slice_(kitchen_utensil)) so I think "egg slice" might be local to the UK as well. Wok Chuan or Wok Spatula seems to get the shape, but you're right I can't find anything that is slotted.

Comment: What about the elevated sides - is there a term for that? I think that may have been a key part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two kinds on ebay, one slotted and one no slots. both under $3,00 and I just purchased several of both for myself and family members:

CRESTWARE NY1 Turner,Slotted,Curved,12-1/4 in. L

CRESTWARE NY2 Turner,Solid,Curved,13 in. L

Hope this helps.

Thomas

Answer (score -1):

I would call it "a fish slice with raised sides".